# How to add interactive labels to treetop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to add interactive labels to my treemap that show the category and percent. Is there a way to do this? Another change I would like to make is to the color. I'd like for the highest numbers to be the darkest shade of a single color. Is this possible? Lately I would like to remove the legend.

```
 # Importing required library 
 library(ggplot2) 
 library(treemapify) 

 # Creating Dataframe 
 df<- data.frame(Fruits=c("Owners' Equivalent Rent of Residences", 
                     "Rent of Primary Residence",
                     "New Vehicles", 
                     "Used Cars and Trucks",
                     "Cereals And bakery Products",
                     "Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair",
                     "Airline Fares",
                     "Apparel", 
                     "Medical Care Commodities",
                     "Alcoholic Beverages", 
                     "Hospital Services",
                     "Tobacco and Smoking",
                     "Physicians Services",
                     "Gasoline All Types",
                     "Electricity", 
                     "Utility (Piped) Gas Services",
                     "Nonalcoholic Beverages and Beverage Materials",
                     "Food Away From Home", 
                     "Meats Poultry Fish and", 
                     "Fruits and Vegetables", 
                     "Dairy and Related Products",
                     "Cereals And Bakery Products", 
                     "Other Foods at Home"), 
            perc=c(6.7, 6.9, 1.3, -3.8, 19.2, 8.5, -12.1, 1.1, 5, 2.9, 
                    6.3, 7.7, 0.7, -8.9, 3.4, -10.4, -2.9, 5.3, 0.1, 0.4, 
                    -1.4, 3.4, 3.3)) 

 # Plotting TreeMap Graph 
 ggplot2::ggplot(df,aes(area=perc,fill=Fruits,label=Fruits))+ 
 treemapify::geom_treemap(layout="squarified")+ 
 geom_treemap_text(place = "centre",size = 12)
 labs(title="Customized Tree Plot using ggplot and treemapify in R")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot2` is a static charting library, i.e. you can't have interactive tooltips. If that is your desired goal then I would suggest to use an interactive charting library like `plotly`, `highcharter` or `echarts4r` to mention a few.

Instead, if you want to stick with the `ggplot2` approach you could get rid of the legend using `guides(fill="none")`. And to color the tiles using shades of one color, you could e.g. map `perc` on fill which will automatically give you a color gradient. Or as a second approach you could create a custom color palette which you can use with `scale_fill_manual`, e.g. in the code below I use the `"Greens"` Brewer palette which I extend to accommodate your 23 categories. Additionally I added the percentage values to the labels.

Finally note that negative values don't make sense for a tree map and actually they get dropped silently.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(treemapify)

pal_fill <- colorRampPalette(scales::brewer_pal(palette = "Greens")(9))
pal_fill <- pal_fill(length(unique(df$Fruits)))
names(pal_fill) <- levels(reorder(df$Fruits, df$perc))

ggplot(df, aes(area = perc, fill = Fruits, label = Fruits)) +
  geom_treemap(layout = "squarified") +
  geom_treemap_text(
    aes(label = paste0(Fruits, "\n", perc, "%")),
    place = "centre", size = 12
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill) +
  labs(title = "Customized Tree Plot using ggplot and treemapify in R") +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

**EDIT** An easy approach to set the text color would be to use `prismatic::best_contrast` inside `after_scale()` which allows to set the text color with the best contrast. And of course could you change the font family, for the labels via the `family` argument, for other text like the title via e.g. the `base_family=` argument of the theme.

```
ggplot(df, aes(area = perc, fill = Fruits, label = Fruits)) +
  geom_treemap(layout = "squarified") +
  geom_treemap_text(
    aes(
      label = paste0(Fruits, "\n", perc, "%"),
      color = after_scale(
        prismatic::best_contrast(
          fill, y = c("white", "black")
        )
      )
    ),
    place = "centre", size = 12,
    family = "Georgia"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill) +
  labs(title = "Customized Tree Plot using ggplot and treemapify in R") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  theme_grey(base_family = "Georgia")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to change the label on "Cereals and Bakery Products" to white so it's more easily readable? Also is there a way to change the label font?

Comment: Sure could this be achieved. See my edit for an automatic approach to choose the text color with the best contrast.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting the following error with your edit :Error in `geom_treemap_text()`:
! Problem while setting up geom aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `loadNamespace()`:
! there is no package called ‘prismatic’
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Well, of course do you have to install the `prismatic` package, i.e. run `install.packages("prismatic")`.